# How to get alert message when user click on outside panel in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have form in which I have several controls. My concern is that when I filling values in Panel1 , & click on any other control or space outside panel1 .How can I get alert message.
I am working in asp.net

Comment: Would you mind showing some of the code involved and what you've tried, please.

Comment: Currently I dont have code on my machine , but I can tell you scenario..

Comment: @Neurofluxation It would help if any of the questions asked had any responses. Guessing those questions have as much detail as this one. :)

Comment: @  Neurofluxation , epascarello : i dont understand what you are trying to tell

Comment: If an answer has helped you, please accept it (click the tick)!

Answer (score 2):

Add a click event to the body. Check the event's target or srcElement to see where the click occured. See if the cilck occurs on an element that is in the panel.

Answer (score 0):

Use focusin and focusout of Jquery.

```
<div style="border: 1px solid black;padding:10px;">
   First name: <input type="text"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text">
</div>`
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("div").focusin(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "#FFFFCC");
});
$("div").focusout(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
});
});
```